# IntelliJ IDEA not recognizing classes specified in Maven dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3

import com.app.abc.*;

abc is being displayed in red color.

verified the .m2/repository. dependency is downloaded.
tried reload of project... deleted all dependencies frm .m2 and downloaded again.. Still does not help

even tried mvn -U idea:idea

Also tried

```
**Right Clicking the pom.xml in Intellij-idea -> Maven - Reload Project.**
```

Tried File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Classes from the dependency are being shown in a list of recommendation by Intellij. But the import statement is causing the error

Comment: mvn dependency:tree is showing the dependency

Comment: Did you find the library’s physical file actually present in your project?